# Where is the build.gradle file of the Android application?

Tags: android, installation, android-studio, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I'm trying to install the Android Support Library with resources on the Android IDE as described here http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res however I don't find any build.gradle file in the folder, where is it located?

Comment: Please post screenshot of your project structure so that we can help you easily.